# Including More Database Connection Options in a Visual Studio Isolated Shell Application?

Tags: visual-studio, vsx, visual-studio-addins, visual-studio-shell

When starting up an isolated mode visual studio shell application, the only databases available in the Tools->Connect to Database are Access, SQL Compact, and SQL Server Database File.

Is there a way to configure the isolated shell to include other database types?  In particular SQL Server and MySQL.  Are there any licensing agreement issues related to including SQL Server support?

Answer (score 1):

This probably was intentional. These connectivity options are in line with what are provided by the freely available Visual Studio Express Editions. In the real Visual Studio, you must have the Professional Edition or better to access standalone database servers. (In fact this limitation is one of the main reasons a lot of developers buy Visual Studio.)

Comment: It may be an intenional default, but is there a way to add to them?Or is there no way?